# Navigate parent.window with a relative url from iframe across domains

Tags: javascript, html

So there is a parent page on one domain that includes an iframe from a different domain.

I am trying to navigate parent page from the iframe using a relative path that would take base url from the parent.

I tried with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function navigateParent(targetPage) {
        var url = window.parent.location.href;
        if (url.indexOf('.') > -1) {
             url = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        }
        window.parent.location = url + targetPage;
     }
</script>
```

but this produces an error:

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL ...my parent url... with URL ...my iframe url... . Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Is there any way to do this? Ie specifiying some cross-domain permission or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross domain protections are now serverly enforced browser-side to protect the user (following some cross domain injections).

To call a function or change a property in a frame/window served by another domain you can

- specify [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) on the server (this tells the browser that cross domain communication is fine)
- preferred : use [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) to communicate between windows and frames